# Getting pivot and reltated tables column values Laravel 3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

Good evening peeps, I'm playing a little bit with Laravel, and I have this situation. I have 2 models and 3 tables to display vital signs from a pacient.

```
Table pacient:
id
names
birthdate

Table vital_sign:
id
description
unit

table pacient_vital_sign
id
pacient_id
vital_sign_id
first_value
second_value
date_time_taken
```

And the 2 models:

```
class Pacient extends Eloquent{
        public static $timestamps = false;
        
        public function vital_signs(){
          return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('VitalSign', 'pacient_vital_sign', 'pacient_id', 'vital_sign_id');
        }
    }

class VitalSign extends Eloquent{
        public static $timestamps = false;
        public static $table = 'vital_signs';
        public function pacients(){
          return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('Pacient', 'pacient_vital_sign', 'vital_sign_id', 'pacient_id');
        }
    }
```

And for my view I'm sending the pacient whose vital signs I want to display:

```
$pacient = Pacient::where('active', '=', 1)->first();
```

So, based on the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#intermediate-tables) I could do this to show the pivotal table data:

```
@foreach($pacient->vital_signs as $sv)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $sv->pivot->date_time_taken }}</td>
        <td>{{ $sv->description }}</td>
        <td>{{ $sv->pivot->first_value }} &nbsp; {{ $sv->pivot->second_value }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

But this way, neither the date_time_taken value nor first_value or second_value is showed. Description is displayed.

Now, if I do something like this

```
@foreach($pacient->vital_signs()->pivot()->get() as $sv)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $sv->date_time_taken }}</td>
        <td>{{ $sv->description }}</td>
        <td>{{ $sv->first_value }} &nbsp; {{ $sv->second_value }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

date_time_taken, first_value and secon_value are displayed but I dont know how to reverse the relationship in order to display the value for the related table column, in this case, description from vital_sign table

So I both cases, I'm missing something. Any ideas? What I'm missings?

Thanks

Comment: In your first `@foreach` how about using `$sv->pivot()->first_value`?

Comment: Tried and throws this error: Method [pivot] is not defined on the Query class

Comment: Ah yes, I guess that makes sense.  I can tell you for certain that the second example won't include `description` because it does not exist on the pivot.  Why the first example of yours is not working I'm sadly not sure.

Comment: oh well.. thanks anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Docs:

> By default only certain fields from the pivot table will be returned
>   (the two id fields, and the timestamps). If your pivot table contains
>   additional columns, you can fetch them too by using the with() method

So in my case, on both models:

```
return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('VitalSign', 'pacient_vital_sign', 'pacient_id', 'vital_sign_id')->with('col1', 'col2', 'coln');
```

and this will work:

```
@foreach($pacient->vital_signs as $sv)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $sv->pivot->date_time_taken }}</td>
        <td>{{ $sv->description }}</td>
        <td>{{ $sv->pivot->first_value }} &nbsp; {{ $sv->pivot->second_value }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this to be useful, but a quick addendum for Laravel 4:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Model','pivot_table','this_id','foreign_id')->withPivot('col1','col2');
```

Comment: The Laravel API has changed and this is the correct answer now.